# jwt function return data after refresh page

Tags: laravel, vue.js, jwt, single-page-application

I'm using JWT for my spa app in vue, with laravel.
i have a function for showing the detail of user in the profile page:

```
public function me(Request $request)
{
  $user = $this->guard('api')->user();
  return response()->json($user);
}
```

the all data is null for the first time and after refresh the page it showing.why?

Comment: Is it possible the first request is sent before the authentication request is sent? Or possibly at the same time?

Comment: Can you confirm in DevTools that the request actually has the JWT token? If you're loading it asynchronously it might not be loaded the first call you call `me`.